# How can I use two instances of gfortran?

Tags: gcc

This is a reask of the question here [How do I install gfortran-7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949308/how-do-i-install-gfortran-7)
I have both gcc-5 and gcc-7 as well as gfortran-5 and gfortran-7. While am able to switch between gcc-5 and gcc-7 with

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7
```

then

```
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

I am not able to modify the above commands to do the same for gfortran.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Checking my fortran install my version is gfortran-5, so to set up alternatives I did:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gfortran gfortran /usr/bin/gfortran-5 60
```

Now when I do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gfortran
```

I see

```
There is only one alternative in link group gfortran (providing /usr/bin/gfortran): 
/usr/bin/gfortran-5
Nothing to configure.
```

Because I have only one install of fortran, so add any other version you wish to use with `update-alternatives and set which to use with same.

Source:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2206425

Comment: Thanks @George. When I try the command it tells me that "update-alternatives: error: alternative gfortran can't be master: it is a slave of gcc" . When I try "sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gfortran gfortran --slave /usr/bin/gfortran-5.4 30", I get "update-alternatives: priority must be an integer". I will keep trying.

Comment: This is how I got round my problem: My software needs the latest gfortran-7.1.  I thought the system may still need the older gfortran-5.  I uninstalled gfortran-5, and made a link of gfortran-7 to gfortran in /usr/bin.  Thank you who spent time looking at my problem.